# How to calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{x^n}\right)^n,\quad x>1?$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

How to calculate $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{x^n}\right)^n,\quad x>1?$$

I don't have an idea to solve that.

If $x>1$ then for $n\to \infty$ satisfy $\dfrac{1}{x^n}\to 0$. Then I have indeterminate form $(1-0)^\infty$. I stuck here. Anyone can give me hint to solve this problem?

Comment: **Hint :** $a^n = \exp \left( n \log(a) \right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e^{-1}.$$
Also, recall that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{x^{n}}=0,\text{ if }\,x>1.$$
So $$ \left(1-\frac{1}{x^{n}}\right)^{n}=\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{n}}\right)^{\frac{x^{n}}{x^{n}}\cdot n}=\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{n}}\right)^{x^{n}\cdot\frac{n}{x^{n}}}=\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{n}}\right)^{x^{n}}\right)^{\frac{n}{x^{n}}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\left(e^{-1}\right)^{0}=1. $$

Answer (score 3):

Bernoulli gives

$$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{x^n}\right)^n \ge 1- \frac{n}{x^n}.$$

Hence

$$1- \frac{n}{x^n} \le \left(1-\dfrac{1}{x^n}\right)^n  \le 1.$$

Can you proceed ?